# When attempting to dual-boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7, boot loader cannot mount root.disk

Tags: installation, dual-boot, wubi, windows-7, filesystem

My PC manufacturer has already allocated all four primary disk partitions, so I attempted to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 using Wubi. When I select Ubuntu from the boot menu, it drops to BusyBox shell and cannot mount the root volume, even though it is visible in the Windows file system. How do I get it to recognize its own pathnames? I am an absolute beginner in Linux command line.

Answer (score 0):

- First make sure you have completely `ShutDown` Windows (not Hibernation, not Sleep, not Restart).
- If Wubi still does not mount, there is little chance to fix it (Wubi is less reliable than a standard Ubuntu install), but you can try following this tutorial: [How_can_I_access_my_Wubi_install_and_repair_my_install_if_it_wont_boot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/#How_can_I_access_my_Wubi_install_and_repair_my_install_if_it_won.27t_boot.3F)